# JSON parse won't convert into Array

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In my code I want to parse JSON data and show Google Maps info windows but When I convert through `JSON.parse()` function and pass it as variable info Maps info windows won't work properly, but when I use `JSON.parse` function to convert and display result in `textarea` then put converted values manually it shows info windows properly

Here is what I return through AJAX/JSON Raw

```
[
    "['<div class=\"info_content\"><h3>test 1<\/h3><h4>Contact: 33<\/h4><p>33<\/p><\/div>']",
    "['<div class=\"info_content\"><h3>test 2<\/h3><h4>Contact: 22<\/h4><p>22<\/p><\/div>']",
    "['<div class=\"info_content\"><h3>test 3<\/h3><h4>Contact: 55<\/h4><p>55<\/p><\/div>']"
]
```

This is what I require to display infowindows

```
[
    ['<div class="info_content"><h3>test 1</h3><h4>Contact: 33</h4><p>33</p></div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content"><h3>test 2</h3><h4>Contact: 22</h4><p>22</p></div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content"><h3>test 3</h3><h4>Contact: 55</h4><p>55</p></div>']
]
```

This is my JS Part which making problem

```
//Ajax Success response
var location_box = JSON.parse(response);
var infoWindowContent = location_box;
// Add multiple markers to map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
```

Complete JS Code

```
<script>
    var markers = [];

    function initMap(location_data, location_box) {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.57951, -4.41387),
        };

        // Display a map on the web page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(50);

        // Multiple markers location, latitude, and longitude
        //alert(location_data);
        var markers = location_data;
        //var markers = [['test 1', 25.1212, 55.1535, 5],['test 2', 25.2084, 55.2719, 6],['test 3', 25.2285, 55.3273, 7]];

        var infoWindowContent = location_box;

        // Add multiple markers to map
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
            marker, i;

        // Place each marker on the map  
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            // Add info window to marker    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Center the map to fit all markers on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        // Set zoom level
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
            this.setZoom(15);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var location_data;
        $("#mapped").on("change", function() {
            var dataname = $(".selectpicker option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "findforwork.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "searchid=" + dataname,
                success: function(response) {
                    //alert('Success' + response);
                    var str_response = response;
                    var res_new = str_response.split("==============");
                    var location_data = JSON.parse(res_new[0].replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/\'/g, "\""));
                    var location_box = res_new[1]; // Info windows Array will be here
                    $('#infoBx').val(location_box);
                    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapDiv, "load", initMap(location_data, location_box));
                }
            }); //End Of Ajax
        }); //End of mapped
    });
</script>
```

PHP Code to generate JSON data

```
$locations  = array();
$locas      = array();
$infoDialog = array();
if (is_numeric($_POST['searchid'])) {
    $service_id = $_POST['searchid'];
    $query      = "SELECT * FROM tblemployees WHERE FIND_IN_SET($service_id, service)";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            // username is already exist 

            $print_info = null;

            $latitude       = $row['ltd'];
            $longitude      = $row['lotd'];
            $person_name    = $row['fullname'];
            $person_id      = $row['id'];
            $person_contact = $row['contact'];
            $person_address = $row['address'];

            $locations[] = array(
                'name' => $person_name,
                'lat' => $latitude,
                'lng' => $longitude,
                'lnk' => $person_id
            );
            $locas[]     = "['" . $person_name . "', " . $latitude . ", " . $longitude . ", " . $person_id . "]";

            $print_info .= '<div class="info_content">';
            $print_info .= '<h3>' . $person_name . '</h3>';
            $print_info .= '<h4>Contact: ' . $person_contact . '</h4>';
            $print_info .= '<p>' . $person_address . '</p>';
            $print_info .= '</div>';

            $infoDialog[] = "['" . $print_info . "']";
        }
    }

    $json_response = json_encode($locas);
    $json_info     = json_encode($infoDialog);
    echo $json_response . "==============" . $json_info;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the raw JSON object here please.

Comment: How are you getting the response? it appears as though whatever is building the response is doing so incorrectly.

Comment: @jburtondev please check my updated question

Comment: @KevinB I am getting through php and ajax

Comment: your php is incorrect then. You should only be using json_encode once, after you've built the whole array. Currently you are json_encoding each item, then the whole thing.

Comment: @KevinB as I am new to php and jquery don't know too much about it I have posted my complete JS code

Comment: the js code isn't relevant to your problem.

Comment: The problem is with the code that is outputting the back data, yet all I see if JavaScript code. Yes, it could be fixed in the JavaScript end, but that is putting a bandaid on the real issue that you have a bug in the PHP code. Show how you build the array in the PHP code.

Comment: @epascarello can you please check my PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not clear if response is an array or a string. If it is a array of strings, you should parse each member, such:

```
var location_box = response.map(x=>JSON.parse(x));
```

This way location_box will be an array of one element arrays.

**EDIT**:

By your code, the response var is a string, so, first parse it:

```
var location_box = JSON.parse(res_new[0]).map(x=>JSON.parse(x));
```

Comment: Can you please check my complete JS code it may help you

Comment: Almost - for me it looks like the response itself must be parsed first: `JSON.parse(response).map(JSON.parse)`.

Comment: @Rtra what does your `response` string exactly look like?

Comment: I am getting this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1 using this `JSON.parse(res_new[1]).map(x=>JSON.parse(x));` from your updated answer

Comment: @naeramarth7 see my question **JSON Raw** part

Comment: In that case, Adilson's initial answer seems right to me, though.

Comment: Rtra, how your raw response is coming? I see you doing some "unescapes" replacing \" but they should be there for you materialize that as an array of strings. Post an example of how response is coming.

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr please check my php code to generate json data

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr I fixed some parts of JS and PHP and tried your solution it works fine thank you so much